# How to prevent Outlook 2016 from adding line breaks in long URLs?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, url, plaintext, linebreaks

It seems Outlook 2016 adds line breaks in plain text messages.

How can I prevent this?

This is how it looks in Outlook 2016
with and without `[x]` in

```
[x] Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages
```

[image: outlook2016]

Comment: I tested and confirmed with **Outlook 2016** the below solution in my answer works for long URLs just as you described when sending as plain text format by simply *unchecking* that option of **Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages**.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I usually work on Linux. Next time, I have to work on this Windows machine, I will test it and report back.

Answer (score 1):

### Outlook 2016 — Prevent Long URL Plain Text Format Line Breaks

> [**Line breaks are removed in posts made in plain text format in Outlook**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/287816/line-breaks-are-removed-in-posts-made-in-plain-text-format-in-outlook)
>
> **Method 1. Disable the feature that removes extra line breaks**
>
> This method disables the feature for all plain text items. To do this,
> follow these steps:
>
> **For Outlook 2010 and later versions:**
>
> 1. Open Outlook.
> 2. On the **File** tab, click **Options**.
> 3. In the **Options** dialog, click **Mail**.
> 4. In the **Message format** section, clear the **Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages** check box.
> 5. Click **OK**.
>
> [Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/287816/line-breaks-are-removed-in-posts-made-in-plain-text-format-in-outlook)

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. The link to this page was broken at the dash `-`, I took a screenshot, but can not attach it in a comment.

Comment: @JonasStein That's very odd but if you could upload the screen shot to https://imgur.com/upload and then comment the URL maybe that'll show me what you are seeing. I'm not sure why you mean about this link to this page being broken unless you are talking about whatever you are testing this method with that is not working. I checked both the hyper links in this answer and both work. I also tested this solution from Outlook 2016 on Windows 10 before posting and it worked for me so I don't understand something but hopefully a screen shot URL link will clarify and I can help further.

Comment: I added the screenshot to the question